# escape % character in zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to add a battery blugin to my prompt https://github.com/Goles/Battery.

```
PROMPT="╭─${user_host} ${current_dir} ${git_branch} `battery`
╰─%B$%b "
RPS1="${return_code}"
```

I need to escape the percent sign, which can be done by getting the string output and then replacing it with two parenthesis, but I have failed at scripting that.  My prompt looks like the top line but I want it to appear like it is in the third line.  Any easy fixes to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have problem executing the `battery` command from the github, but I may know you problem. I use zsh too.
In zsh you have to add additional % sign to escape the %.
You can try to change the `battery` command to `battery | sed 's/%/%%/'`, i.e, your prompt should look like this:

```
PROMPT="╭─${user_host} ${current_dir} ${git_branch} `battery | sed 's/%/%%/'`
╰─%B$%b "
```